# Adding cell values to indirect cell location

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to generate a function with VBA that automatically adds Values from one cell of a defined range of an Excel Sheet to the cell on it's right, so that for example when you put a number in A1 that number will automatically be added to the value in A2 (and deleted in A1). This is what my first idea looked like:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

For Each cell In Range("A1:A100")
If cell.Value > 0 Then
cell.Offset(0, 1).Value = cell.Offset(0, 1).Value + cell.Value
cell.ClearContents
End If
Next

End Sub
```

Unfortunately this will give me the error "Out of stack space" and this is where my knowledge on VBA ends. Does anybody have any suggestions on different approaches?

Comment: Do you mean move the value from A1 to B1? That's what your code reflects. `obj.Offset(r, c)`

Answer (score 0):

**You are very close!**

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Application.EnableEvents = False
        For Each cell In Range("A1:A100")
            If cell.Value > 0 Then
                cell.Offset(0, 1).Value = cell.Offset(0, 1).Value + cell.Value
                cell.ClearContents
            End If
        Next
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

You must disable events during the processing. Otherwise you can get into an infinite loop.
You can also refine this code to make it run MUCH FASTER!

Answer (score 0):

It appears as though you're recursing the function.

You're using `OnChange` to make a change, triggering `OnChange` again.

My advice would be to use the event argument `Target` and only operate on the changed cell.

Something like

```
Target.offset(0,1).value = Target.offset(0,1).value + Target.value
Target.ClearContents
```

Edit: @Gary's suggestion too. Need to disable events.